# Search a list through an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have a class `Bookstore` that implements an interface `IBookstore`.

`Bookstore` has as a private property a list of books: `private List<Book> AllBooks;`

I don't want to expose the entire list of books through the interface. Instead, I want the user to query books based on certain properties. So, in `IBookstore` I have the following:

```
public interface IBookstore
{
    IList<Book> SelectedBooks;
}
public class Bookstore : IBookstore
{
    private List<Book> AllBooks;
    public IList<Book> SelectedBooks { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do is create a method in called `SearchBooks` that will search the list AllBooks for all entries containing various properties, and then set `SelectedBooks` with the result. So, my usage would be the following:

```
Bookstore myStore = new Bookstore();
...
myStore.SearchBooks( A BUNCH OF CRITERIA );
myStore.SelectedBooks; // contains books selected by the criteria passed to SearchBooks above
```

Why I would like to do this:

- I will need to access `SelectedBooks` many times. I do not want to
  run the search many times.
- I want the list of SelectedBooks to be a property of `myBookstore`. This object is created once and used in many places, so I want to be able to access the same `SelectedBooks` in many places without having to re-construct it. Storing it as a local property is not desirable; i.e., I do not want to do `List<Book> myBooks = myStore.SearchBooks( A BUNCH OF CRITERIA);`. I have a very good reason for this.

**My question**

Given that `Book` has many properties, e.g. `Title`, `Author`, `Date`, etc., what is the easiest way to arbitrarily pass a set of search criteria to `SearchBooks` so that I can search my list privately within `Bookstore`?

For example, if I had access to the entire list in my application, I could use Linq. Could I pass a Linq query to a method and have the query execute privately within `myBookstore`?

Comment: Have you considered caching the search results by the criteria? If memory is not a worry you could do this, then just return your results from the `SearchBooks(...)` method.

Comment: @Aaron Yes. And I don't want to do that.

Comment: The reason I do not want to cache the results is because I am writing code for Unity3D, and in Unity I can create an instance of an object and have it persist across multiple levels and multiple GameObjects. If I cache the results when I query them, then the results are scoped to the GameObject in which they're created, and if I want to pass them back and forth to other GameObjects, then I have to write control logic, or I have to re-execute the query. I'd rather just keep the results in `myBookstore`, because I can then access the results anywhere without having to do any additional work.

Comment: Have you tried actually to do the query which searches through the books? Now you have only a shell which actually does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could I pass a Linq query to a method and have the query execute privately within myBookstore?

You can pass delegate:

```
public void SearchBooks(Func<IEnumerable<Book>, IEnumerable<Book>> query)
{
    SelectedBooks = query(AllBooks).ToList();
}
```

call example:

```
myStore.SearchBooks(c => c.Where(b => b.Title == "test" && b.Author == "author"));
```

or just a set of predicates:

```
public void SearchBooks(params Func<Book, bool>[] predicates)
{
    var query = AllBooks.AsEnumerable();
    foreach(var p in predicates)
        query = query.Where(p);

    SelectedBooks = query.ToList();
}
```

call example:

```
myStore.SearchBooks(x => x.Title == "test", x => x.Author == "author");
```

Comment: Why does he just do the query inside the method? Any special reason?

Comment: @marko Yes, because I want the results stored in `myBookstore`. I want as a property of `myBookstore` a list of books resulting from the most recently performed query.

Comment: Marcin, thank you, I believe this is exactly what I need. I'm not familiar with how I would use it, though. How would I structure the arguments?

Comment: I've added examples how you can call these methods. The second one is more strict: you can only filter items. The first one allows you to pass a lot more stuff, like filtering, ordering, maybe even grouping, as long as the logic takes and returns `IEnumerable<Book>`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't go through all the troubles of trying to abstract the concept of a *query*. Instead, use LINQ directly on the list of books.

You can expose the list of books as an enumerable sequence.

```
public interface IBookstore
{
    IEnumerable<Book> Books;
}
```

And then you can query it through LINQ in any way you like.

```
IBookstore store;   // Some store.
var johngreenBooks = from book in store.Books
                     where book.Author == "John Green"
                     orderby book.Title
                     select book;
```

If you don't want to evaluate the query every time you enumerate it, make it a list or array.

```
var johngreenBookArray = johngreenBooks.ToArray();
```

You can pass this array (or list) around, or tuck it away somewhere. In my mind the query I use to select some books is independent of the book store, so I wouldn't store the result in the store.